# Error: failed to checkpoint one or more containers

Tags: docker, checkpoint

I use docker-1.10.0-dev to checkpoint a docker container. But there happened a problem.

```
./docker-1.10.0-dev checkpoint looper
 Error response from daemon: page not found
 Error: failed to checkpoint one or more containers
```

I download this docker on http://criu.org/Docker